# Error from selenium : AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was learning selenium for python automation, but I am stuck with following error. Can anyone please help me?

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
website = 'https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'
path = r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path))
driver.get(website)
driver.quit()
```

Error log,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "e:/[ FreeCourseWeb.com ] Udemy - Web Scraping Course in Python - BS4, Selenium and Scrapy/~Get Your Files Here !/Python-Bots-and-Web-Scrapping-Projects/Scraping using selenium/selenium_scrapper.py", line 5, in 
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path))
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81,
> in **init**
> super().**init**(
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 103, in **init**
> self.service.start()
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 106, in start
> PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> & "C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe" "e:/[ FreeCourseWeb.com ] Udemy - Web Scraping Course in Python - BS4, Selenium and Scrapy/~Get Your Files Here !/Python-Bots-and-Web-Scrapping-Projects/Scraping using selenium/selenium_scrapper.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "e:/[ FreeCourseWeb.com ] Udemy - Web Scraping Course in Python - BS4, Selenium and Scrapy/~Get Your Files Here !/Python-Bots-and-Web-Scrapping-Projects/Scraping using selenium/selenium_scrapper.py", line 5, in 
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path))
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in **init**
> super().**init**(
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 103, in **init**
> self.service.start()
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 106, in start
> self.assert_process_still_running()
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 117, in assert_process_still_running
> return_code = self.process.poll()
> AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are working on Windows OS computer.
If so, `path` should include `exe` executable file extension.
In your case:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
website = 'https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'
path = "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path))
driver.get(website)
```

My working code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
```

Where `C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe` is the actual location of `chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have another question if you reply it will help me,
my code is(only main part),

web = 'https://www.audible.com/search'
container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'adbl-impression-container')
products = container.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//li')
for product in products[:5]:
    book_title.append(product.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h3[contains(@class,"bc-heading")]').text)

but,every time I got an empty list,can you please see this

Answer (score 0):

in my case (Windows OS) this works:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

    path =r"C:\path\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
    service = Service(executable_path=path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    web = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup'
    driver.get(web)
```

Cheers.